# If $0<a<1$, why $a=\frac{1}{1+b}$ for some $b>0\,$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I admit $\frac{1}{1+b}<1$ is trivial for $b>0.$ However, the above claim boils down to suggesting that, any $y\in\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x>1\}$ can be uniquely represented by $1+b$ for some $b>0.$ Can you give me some hints how to prove it?

Comment: Now what is it? $|a|<1$ or $a>1$?

Comment: I just edited it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be $0<a<1$, othervise it doesn't hold. Say $a=-1/2$ then $b=-3$

Let $c= 1/a$ then $c>1$ since $1>a>0$. Let $b=c-1>0$. So $a= {1\over 1+b}$.

Comment: Thank you. I just needed to clarify. Have a nice day.

Comment: No problem, you too.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-Because if $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x}$ then $f([0,+\infty[)=]0,1]$